# Prove that $\sqrt{n+1}>\sqrt{n}+\frac{1}{2\sqrt{n}}-\frac{1}{8n\sqrt{n}}$

Tags: inequality

> Prove that $\sqrt{n+1}>\sqrt{n}+\frac{1}{2\sqrt{n}}-\frac{1}{8n\sqrt{n}}$ if $n>0$.

I didn't see an easy way of proving this without doing a lot of algebra and rearranging. Is there an easier way?

Comment: $n$ is a real number or an integer?

Comment: @LivaditisAlex It doesn't matter but we should prove it for integer.

Comment: This looks very similar to the commonly used approximation method known as the Babylonian Method to two iterations (with some algebraic manipulation... See also Bakhshali Approximation).  An interesting proof might be extracted from that result

Answer (score 6):

It is hardly a lot of algebra. To save on MathJax, I write $\sqrt n$ as $s$. So the square of the RHS is $(s+\frac{1}{2s}-\frac{1}{8s^3})^2=1+s^2+\frac{1}{64s^6}-\frac{1}{8s^4}$. The square of the LHS is just $1+s^2$.

So you have to show that $\frac{1}{8s^4}>\frac{1}{64s^6}$ or $8s^2>1$ or $8n>1$ which is true for any positive integer and indeed any real $>\frac{1}{8}$.

Comment: A pretty answer! (+1)

Comment: But it holds for any real number, so squaring is not reversible.

Comment: The LHS is guaranteed positive because it means the positive square root (and it exists because $n$+1 is positive). So you can reverse. (If you get a negative number on the RHS, then it is certainly true).

Comment: But your answer does not reflect that (you said any real greater than one eighth when it holds for any real).

Answer (score 4):

It does not look so terrible to me! We have:
$$ \sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}} \tag{1}$$
and:
$$ \frac{1}{2\sqrt{n}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}=\frac{\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}}{2\sqrt{n}\left(\sqrt{n}+\sqrt{n+1}\right)}=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{n}\left(\sqrt{n}+\sqrt{n+1}\right)^2}\tag{2}$$
so the inequality boils down to $\sqrt{n}+\sqrt{n+1}>2\sqrt{n}$, quite trivial.

Answer (score 2):

For $y>0, (1+y)^{-3/2}<1$. Integrate both sides from $0$ to $x$:

$$2\left(1-(1+x)^{-1/2}\right)=\int_0^x(1+y)^{-3/2}\,dy<\int_0^x\,dy=x$$

which, upon rearranging, gives that $1-\frac{x}{2}<(1+x)^{-1/2}$. We now integrate from $0$ to $1/n$:

$$\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{4n^2}=\int_0^{1/n}\left(1-\frac{x}{2}\right)\,dx<\int_0^{1/n}(1+x)^{-1/2}\,dx=2\left(\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{1/2}-1\right)$$

which, upon further rearranging, gives:

$$\sqrt\frac{n+1}{n}=\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{1/2}>1+\frac{1}{2n}-\frac{1}{8n^2}$$

Multiplying by $\sqrt n$ gives the desired result.